# Sed command to strip pattern when found and add it between square [] to following lines until new one is found

Tags: sed, strip

This is my starting point.

```
#CHECK THISOUT
------EXAMPLE 1------ ; http://www.idontneed.com
Google ; http://www.google.com
Yahoo ; http://www.yahoo.com
------EXAMPLE 2------ ; http://idontcare.com
Ebay ; http://www.ebay.com
Amazon ; http://www.amazon.com
```

The pattern to match is the string with ------SOMETHING------

The desired output is:

```
#CHECK THISOUT
[------EXAMPLE 1------]  Google ; http://www.google.com
[------EXAMPLE 1------]  Yahoo ; http://www.yahoo.com
[------EXAMPLE 2------]  Ebay ; http://www.ebay.com
[------EXAMPLE 2------]  Amazon ; http://www.amazon.com
```

Comment: Is the replacement text always at the beginning of the line?  It makes a dramatic difference to how easy it is.

Comment: always in the beginning , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy in `sed`:

```
sed -e '/^------..*------/,$ {
         /^\(------..*------\).*/ { s//[\1]/; h; d; }
         G; s/\(.*\)\n\(\[.*\]\)/\2 \1/
        }' data
```

Explanation:

- Until the trigger pattern is found, lines are printed normally; the script only changes anything from when the first pattern is found.  Then the remainder of the script operates.
- If the line is the trigger pattern, capture the pattern and enclose it in square brackets (`s/…/…/`).
- Copy the pattern to the hold space (`h`).
- Delete the line and move onto the next.
- This is a line without the trigger pattern.
- Append the contents of the hold space to the pattern space after a newline (`G`).
- Split the pattern space into 'before the newline' and 'after the newline' and reorder with a space between (`s/…/…/`).
- Let the ordinary 'print at the end of the cycle' print the result.

If you want two spaces instead of one between the square brackets and the remainder, add an extra space in the second `s/…/…/`.

Example output:

```
#CHECK THISOUT
[------EXAMPLE 1------] Google ; http://www.google.com
[------EXAMPLE 1------] Yahoo ; http://www.yahoo.com
[------EXAMPLE 2------] Ebay ; http://www.ebay.com
[------EXAMPLE 2------] Amazon ; http://www.amazon.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -ne 'if (/^(------.*------) ;.*/) { $h = $1 }
          elsif ($h) { print "[$h]  $_" }
          else {print}' < input > output
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- if a line contains the patters, it's stored in the `$h` variable
- if the pattern is not present, but it has been set before, it's printed with the line appended
- otherwise, the line is printed (prints the first lines before any pattern has been met)

Comment: @Francesco: Is `awk` present?

Comment: yes it isUsage: awk [OPTIONS] [AWK_PROGRAM] [FILE]...

        -v VAR=VAL      Set variable
        -F SEP          Use SEP as field separator
        -f FILE         Read program from FILE

Answer (score 1):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk for clarity, portability, efficiency, simplicity, enhancability, robustness, etc., etc.:

```
awk 'match($0,/-{5}.+-{5}/,a){ v="["a[0]"]  "; next } {print v $0}' file
#CHECK THISOUT
[------EXAMPLE 1------]  Google ; http://www.google.com
[------EXAMPLE 1------]  Yahoo ; http://www.yahoo.com
[------EXAMPLE 2------]  Ebay ; http://www.ebay.com
[------EXAMPLE 2------]  Amazon ; http://www.amazon.com
```

The above uses GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match(), with other awks it'd be:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/-{5}.+-{5}/){ v="["substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)"]  "; next } {print v $0}' file
#CHECK THISOUT
[------EXAMPLE 1------]  Google ; http://www.google.com
[------EXAMPLE 1------]  Yahoo ; http://www.yahoo.com
[------EXAMPLE 2------]  Ebay ; http://www.ebay.com
[------EXAMPLE 2------]  Amazon ; http://www.amazon.com
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` solution, similar to [choroba's perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39818608/4082052). Uses `;` as field separator, so there is an extra space

```
$ cat ip.txt 
#CHECK THISOUT
------EXAMPLE 1------ ; http://www.idontneed.com
Google ; http://www.google.com
Yahoo ; http://www.yahoo.com
------EXAMPLE 2------ ; http://idontcare.com
Ebay ; http://www.ebay.com
Amazon ; http://www.amazon.com

$ awk -F';' '{ if(/^------.*------/){ h = $1 } else if(h){ print "[" h "] " $0 } else {print} }' ip.txt
#CHECK THISOUT
[------EXAMPLE 1------ ] Google ; http://www.google.com
[------EXAMPLE 1------ ] Yahoo ; http://www.yahoo.com
[------EXAMPLE 2------ ] Ebay ; http://www.ebay.com
[------EXAMPLE 2------ ] Amazon ; http://www.amazon.com
```